# SQL Server 2008R2 not sending database mail

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail

I have 2 servers, a SQL Server 2012 and a SQL Server 2008R2.

Database mail works fine on the 2012 but does not work at all on the 2008R2.

The account and profile settings are the same on the two servers, and on both servers mail sent with the .NET mail interface goes through okay.

I cannot find any differences between the SQL Server instances.

The message I get is:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 4 (2016-10-28T14:34:57). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it **************:25).

SQL Server Agent is disabled on both servers, so that is not a factor.

The `machine.config` and `web.config` files are basically the same on both servers.

I have followed all the steps outlined in the msdn information, and yet nothing works yet.

Is there something else I should be looking at on the SQL Server 2008R2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.

It is a McAfee setting on our production server.

The setting on the development server is not the same.

The setting in question blocks port 25.

It is discussed in the following:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic956956-146-1.aspx